# WSO2 Integration

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am trying to integrate WSO2 with Mule.  I have taken the WSDL from cxf-services-ws-discovery-api.jar under the org\apache\cxf\ws\discovery\wsdl folder and put it into SOAP UI and hit the URL   on localhost port 9443 and it works fine.  However, when I add the WSDL to my Mule project and generate the client stub using cxf-codegen-plugin and run it I get the following error;

```
ERROR 2014-10-08 16:25:31,545 [main] com.deic.RegistryLifecycle: Trace: 
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: @Action and @WebMethod(action="" does not match on operation    probeOp
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl.setWsaActions(JavaMethodImpl.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl.<init>(JavaMethodImpl.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:664)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:506)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:337)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:102)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:75)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:803)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:810)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:786)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:407)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:384)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:366)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
at org.oasis_open.docs.ws_dd.ns.discovery._2009._01.Discovery.getDiscoveryProxy(Discovery.java:79)
at com.deic.RegistryManager.getDiscoveryProxyPort(RegistryManager.java:29)
at com.deic.RegistryManager.getEndoint(RegistryManager.java:35)
at com.deic.RegistryLifecycle.start(RegistryLifecycle.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237)
at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:273)
at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:152)
at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:123)
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:76)
at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:136)
at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91)
at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87)
at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69)
at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:278)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:123)
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98)
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:297)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:150)
```

This is the cxf-codegen-plugin;

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdd-discovery-1.1-wsdl-os.wsdl</wsdl>            
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-noAddressBinding</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This is the generated class that is blowing up;

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01", name = "DiscoveryProxy")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface DiscoveryProxy {

@Oneway
@Action(input = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Hello")
@WebMethod(operationName = "HelloOp", action = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/HelloOp")
public void helloOp(
    @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "Hello", targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01")
    HelloType parameters
);

@WebResult(name = "ProbeMatches", targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01", partName = "parameters")
@Action(input = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Probe", output = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ProbeMatches")
@WebMethod(operationName = "ProbeOp", action = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ProbeOp")
public ProbeMatchesType probeOp(
    @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "Probe", targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01")
    ProbeType parameters
);

@Oneway
@Action(input = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Bye")
@WebMethod(operationName = "ByeOp", action = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ByeOp")
public void byeOp(
    @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "Bye", targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01")
    ByeType parameters
);

@WebResult(name = "ResolveMatches", targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01", partName = "parameters")
@Action(input = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Resolve", output = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ResolveMatches")
@WebMethod(operationName = "ResolveOp", action = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ResolveOp")
public ResolveMatchesType resolveOp(
    @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "Resolve", targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01")
    ResolveType parameters
);
```

}

I am not sure why SOAP UI has no issue with the WSDL but the client stub does.  I tried to use wireshark but not sure how to configure for HTTPS.  I googled and googled, but cannot work out what is going wrong with the generation of the class, obviously it has to do with the @Action and @WebMethod generated, but I am not sure what I have to do to fix the WSDL to make it work.

Here is the WSDL;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions
    targetNamespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01"
    xmlns:tns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01"
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema>
      <xs:import
          namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01"
          schemaLocation="wsdd-discovery-1.1-schema-os.xsd" />
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="HelloMessage" >
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Hello" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="ByeMessage" >
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Bye" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="ProbeMessage" >
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Probe" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="ProbeMatchMessage" >
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ProbeMatches" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="ResolveMessage" >
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Resolve" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="ResolveMatchMessage" >
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ResolveMatches" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="DiscoveryProxy">
    <wsdl:operation name="HelloOp" >
      <wsdl:input message="tns:HelloMessage"
      wsaw:Action
      ="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Hello"
      />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ByeOp" >
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ByeMessage"
      wsaw:Action
      ="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Bye"
      />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ProbeOp" >
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ProbeMessage"
      wsaw:Action
      ="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Probe"
      />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:ProbeMatchMessage"
      wsaw:Action
      ="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ProbeMatches"
      />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ResolveOp" >
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ResolveMessage"
      wsaw:Action
      ="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/Resolve"
      />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:ResolveMatchMessage"
      wsaw:Action
      ="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ResolveMatches"
      />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="DiscoveryProxy" type="tns:DiscoveryProxy">
    <soap:binding style="document" 
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="HelloOp">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/HelloOp" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ByeOp">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ByeOp" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ProbeOp">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ProbeOp" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ResolveOp">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/ns/discovery/2009/01/ResolveOp" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="Discovery">
        <wsdl:port name="DiscoveryUDP" binding="tns:DiscoveryProxy">
            <soap:address location="soap.udp://:9443"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="DiscoveryProxy" binding="tns:DiscoveryProxy">
            <soap:address location="${discovery_proxy_url}"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service> 
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The only thing I modified on the WSDL was the soap:address on the wsdl:service.  The exception is thrown in the following code when it calls getDiscoveryProxy();

```
Discovery service = new Discovery();
DiscoveryProxy port = service.getDiscoveryProxy();
```

I appreciate any help or advice you can give.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the @Action(input = "url") needs to match the @WebMethod(action = "url"), it appears that the wsdl from the apache libs has them as different url values.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I had a similar issue creating a stub from a WSDL describing a Web Service I am integrating into a Java application, and your auto-answer helped me point out the issue.

To fix the issue, you have to manually edit the WSDL and then re-create the client stub.

For each operation, make the wsamAction property's URL the same as soapAction property's URL:

```
<operation name="operationName">
      <input message="xxx" wsam:Action="http://your.name.space/operationName">
    </input>
.
.
.
    </operation>
```

same as

```
<operation name="operationName">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://your.name.space/operationName" />
 .
 .
 .
</operation>
```

Then re-create the client stub.  It should work seamlessly now.

Hope this helps.